# Is it possible to download this db_Class.php file from Parent Directory?

Tags: php, file, download, directory, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3xEw.png)

[image]

I found a link of a parent directory from one local server.And I want to download this file folders...so their any process to download this db_Class.php files?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-force-download-of-a-php-file-instead-of-execute-it-on-server/4173/3

Answer (score -1):

Not as it is right now. You will either have to:

- Access the files directly (over FTP or SMB)
- Reconfigure the server to send .php-files without processing them (security risk)
- Create a .php-file that can send you the contents of any file, as Anant suggested (bigger security risk)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to get the contents of the file? You should use one of the methods in my answer. Can't use any of those methods? Then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Since OP is accessing the site on a local network, OP should check if the folder is on his own 'puter or his pal's. If on his own, he can browse to the folder and copy the file using Windows Explorer or whatever the appropriate tool may be. If on his pal's, he should ask his pal for a permission and then e.g. pop in for a visit with a USB stick, unless his pal is kind enough to zip up and email the file, or provide OP with network access to his 'puter beyond Apache. I hope OP isn't trying to steal someone's homework. ^_^